# Texturing and shading problem

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

everyone, I'm working on an interior model, but whenever I go to my shading editor, my node setup doesn't display.
.any help?

Comment: Two immediate possibilities spring to mind: Make sure that 'Use Nodes' is checked in the shader menu bar and press the 'Home' key in case the node setup is off-screen.

Comment: Make sure the shader editor is set to *Object*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJQu.png

Comment: Hello John, your suggestion worked just fine..I'm grateful

Comment: @iroh Good! I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Dupe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55338/cant-see-material-nodes-in-node-editor

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate possibilities spring to mind: Make sure that 'Use Nodes' is checked in the shader menu bar and press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key in case the node setup is off-screen.